# Syntax error in if statement Python

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, syntax-error

For some reason I get a syntax error on this function.

```
def log(user, successful):
if successful == True:
    with open('userlog.txt', 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.append(datetime.datetime + ' User ' + user + ' Logged in'
else:
    with open('userlog.txt', 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.append(datetime.datetime + ' Unsuccessful login attempt as ' + user) )
```

Here is the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\conf.py", line 4, in <module>
    import func
  File "C:\func.py", line 48
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Now, i've seen other posts that say I should add an extra parenthesis when this happens. I tried it and it didnt work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whitespace in the code you've posted is broken. Can you fix it?

Comment: it look likes indentation error, for if and else

Comment: You didn't close your parenthesis on the previous line

Comment: @Andy: you beat me to it! I was just about to say that

Comment: The indentation is fine in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you copy/pasted some code wrong.  This line needs a closing parenthesis:

```
logfile.append(datetime.datetime + ' User ' + user + ' Logged in'
#                                                                ^
```

and this one has an extra closing parenthesis:

```
logfile.append(datetime.datetime + ' Unsuccessful login attempt as ' + user) )
#                                                                            ^
```

Simply move the extra parenthesis from the second line to the first and all will be well.

---

Actually, you have one more problem.  As @MartijnPieters said in the comments, you cannot concatenate a `datetime.datetime` object with strings.

I *think* you actually meant to do:

```
logfile.append(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ' Unsuccessful login attempt as ' + user)
```

This will return the current time as a string, which can then be concatenated with other strings:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.datetime.now())
'2014-12-15 13:03:49.242187'
>>>
```

Comment: I saw that right after I posted and fixed it. I feel dumb now.

Comment: The `datetime.datetime` object will not so easily be concatenated to strings either. It should also be *called*, not just referenced.

Comment: Right, I missed that.  Thanks.